chrome not firing visibilitychanged event but Edge and Firefox are for switching tabs
I have this piece of code at the start of my page's script tag:
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
  console.log("in event handler: ", document.visibilityState);
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    console.log("stopping hub");
  }
  else {
    console.log("starting hub");
  }
}, false);

When the page runs in Edge or Firefox, this works perfectly.
Each time I switch tabs, I get a message with the appropriate vibility flag. But when I run the same page on Chrome, I don't get the console.log() messages.
I just can't figure out why chrome isn't sending the page these messages.
I have also replaced with window with document.
Since I have jquery on this page, I have also used $(document).on().
Each time, everything works great in Edge / Firefox, but does not in Chrome.

what kind of tabs ? like this one : https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ ?

That's working for me in Chrome. Perhaps you have some console filter hiding it, or some extension interfering.

Yea, I thought it was strange that it wasn't working in Chrome but worked in the other browsers.  I will check for extensions. There isn't a filter in place, I get all the other console.logs just fine.

By tabs, I mean actual browser tabs. This event is supposed to fire when your page becomes active / inactive. So when the user minimizes or restores the browser, or switches from your page's browser tab to another browser tab.
